# Facing issue while building next app using npm run build

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dev-to-production, nextjs-dynamic-routing

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/actions/user". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7Bdata%2C%20error%2C%20loading%2C%20mutate%2C%20isValidating%7D for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
   
    at a.b.read (D:\Portfolio\portfolio\portfolioapp\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at Object.exports.renderToString (D:\Portfolio\portfolio\portfolioapp\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)       
    at Object.renderPage (D:\Portfolio\portfolio\portfolioapp\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:751:45)
    at Object.defaultGetInitialProps (D:\Portfolio\portfolio\portfolioapp\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:389:51)
    at Function.getInitialProps (D:\Portfolio\portfolio\portfolioapp\.next\server\pages\_document.js:502:20)
    at Object.loadGetInitialProps (D:\Portfolio\portfolio\portfolioapp\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\utils.js:69:29)
```

I am trying to build project and triigered `npm run build` command for generating production app build but seems like thier is issue with prerendering of some the pages

[image]

Comment: If you can just post the code from `/actions/user` then I will be able to find the root cause, but seems like an issue with pre-render functions.

Comment: Yes sure, Thanks @MaheshMore,PFA

``
import useSWR from 'swr';
import  fetcher  from '../actions/index';

 const useGetUser=()=>{
const {data,error,...rest}=useSWR('/api/v1/user',fetcher);
return {data,error,loading:!data && !error,...rest};
}

export default useGetUser;